# TinyMCE toolbar show on click and hide on click-out

Tags: jquery, click, tinymce, menubar

I can´t figure out, how to show/hide TinyMCE menubar on click.

It is impossible to call click event on divs, because there is an iframe over it. It works with Tiny setup, but only in editor.
If you click on menubar, it again disappears.

I think you will get it better, if you see demo:

Any advices? Thanks

**HTML**

```
<textarea>Test</textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

  $(window).click(function() {
    $(".mce-toolbar-grp").hide();
  });

  $(".mce-toolbar-grp").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    menubar: false,
    init_instance_callback: function(ed) {
      $($(this)[0]["editorContainer"]).find(".mce-toolbar-grp").hide();
    },
    setup: function(ed) {
      ed.on("click", function() {
        $(".mce-toolbar-grp").show();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oy5bqtmh/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is effectively the inline editing mode that TinyMCE already provides:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/inline/

Is there a reason you don't want to use inline editing?

Comment: Hey, I can't use the inline editor, as I need a textarea for my validation rules.
Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you create a set of hidden textareas and just place copies of the content there?  Then when you submit the form include the texarea content and not the inline div content?  There is no built in way to make the toolbar work like inline mode while in traditional mode.